# How to get auto completion of Drools in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, drools

Auto completion of Drools (5.5.0.Final) seems not out of the box by default in Eclipse Juno SR1.

What I did are

1. download eclipse-jee-juno-SR1-win32-x86_64.zip, unzip it
2. add update site http://download.jboss.org/drools/release/5.5.0.Final/org.drools.updatesite/, install
3. download drools-distribution-5.5.0.Final.zip, unzip it
4. specify the Drools runtime
5. import existing project from drools-distribution-5.5.0.Final\examples\sources
6. restart
7. confirm that I can compile and run the example

After all these, I can Ctrl-click to jump to class declaration, have auto completion right after I typed "." **ONLY in java files**. None of these are working in drl files.

I know Drools doesnt have auto completion for classes nor functions defined in Drools files yet. I am not asking for that. I am just asking for auto completion for the java classes etc. inside drl files.

Could you please tell me if there are any configuration that I have missed for the auto completion and Ctrl-click to work in drl files as well?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I guess that's available on JBoss Developer Studio (Disclaimer: I'm not related with JBoss nor Red Hat in any means).

Comment: If it is in JBDS, would there be a plugin or custom configuration that make it works in Eclipse as well?

Comment: I don't think so, that's why you should pay for that IDE.

Comment: Wait, isnt JBDS free? I am using it freely, where I have downloaded it from the official web site.

Comment: Sorry, I just used the paid edition so didn't know there was a free edition as well.

Answer (score 0):

I did exactly what you described here, and afaik, this is working.  You should be able to get basic code completion in the rule conditions and consequence.

Answer (score 0):

For drl, eclipse + drools plug should have the code completion for java class. But such feature doesn't work for dslr. I am not sure whether JBoss Developer Studio has extra or not.